# White space in ngx-quill

Tags: html, css, angular, whitespace, ngx-quill

I use the ngx-quill editor and have a white space problem. The problem occurs when editing text. I try to insert an earlier generated html into the editor, but waste the white characters.

```
<quill-editor #editor [modules]="modules" formControlName="description" [style]="{height: '200px'}"></quill-editor>
```

I tried to overwrite styles:

```
quill-editor {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

When adding it in styles, the editor has additional space over the toolbar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUx1S.png)

I see that class ql-editor has white-space: pre-wrap but not work for me.
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try out by adding this to css, then it will replace the white space to

```
:host /deep/ .ql-editor {
  white-space: normal!important;
}
```

or

```
.ql-editor {
  white-space: normal!important;
}
```